# Should I take additional precautions to use Parallels shared folder on Linux?

Tags: unix, virtualization, parallels-desktop, virtualbox, compatibility

On macOS Catalina I installed Debian 10 i386 on Parallels, installed the vm tools also. Everything looks fine.

I would like to play with Qt projects on both platforms. Since Qt is multi platform that should work.

So I created a simple Qt project on macOS, compile and run, fine. Shared that folder on Parallels , so Debian should read/write there also. Went to Konsole on Debian, hit qmake, that was fine. Then to the problem, when I run make I get some strange charactes:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Your question title asks something else than your post, can you please clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: Also, what is in `main.cpp`? From the output it looks like you are trying to compile a binary file.